# Move Email Attachments for Microsoft Exchange Server to Filesystem?

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010

So, Exchange Servers just grow and grow. One option is to use archival software to move emails, etc. out of the server...but recently I thought, "Why move the emails out at all?" If one could remove the file attachments the store wouldn't increase in size nearly as much...and theoretically, it would be possible to link to the files on the filesystem in the email, so the user experience would be the same. I was wondering if such a solution was already in existence?

Comment: May I ask why you are even considering this, as Exchange 2010 databases can safely grow up to 2TB in size, and get more than enough I/O from regular 7200 rpm disks?

Comment: Do hard disks cost you less money if they're used to store flat files instead of a database? What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Moving individual flat files is much easier than migrating a large single file (e.g. database).

Answer (score 1):

MailArchiva Enterprise edition can remove attachments and stub with a reference to a different data store.

https://www.mailarchiva.com/enterprisefeatures